# fs.readFileSync happening before multer uploaded files, ENOENT error

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, multer

I am developing a platform where users should be able to create a hotel via an HTML form. Inside the form, there is an option to upload multiple image files.

I am using multer to handle the upload. My procedure is the following:

Create directory 'images'

1. Save uploaded images in 'images' directory
2. convert images in 'images' directory to base64
3. save base64-format in an array
4. save array in Hotel MongoDB Schema
5. delete directory 'images'

The upload and saving work perfectly but I get an error when I try to upload the next hotel:

```
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open 'C:\ ...'
```

The images are successfully stored in the 'images' directory, but obviously, as the app crashes, nothing is done with the files so I have to delete them manually.

As this is only happening on the second try (when restarting the application, it works again) I assume that `fs.readFileSync` is executed before the images are done uploading. I am clueless as multer is part of my router chain, the conversion to base64 should happen AFTER all files are uploaded to the server.

What am I doing wrong?

Multer functions: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wz167.png
Base64 conversion: https://i.stack.imgur.com/oOEmR.png
Delete function (executed after saving to DB) https://i.stack.imgur.com/PlTvH.png

Comment: What's the point of saving images in the image folder if you want immediately delete them from the disk and save into db? Why not just doinf #3 and #4?

Comment: My thought process was that I need to store the images somewhere to complete actions with them. How can I access images without saving them?

Comment: I don't know what's your background story to process images only from the disk but you can get base64 on image upload and you can push it to DB right away. p.s if you post your code here not as an image would be more helpful

Comment: Yurgh, [no images of code please](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) .....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple snippet to get images as a base64.
Without storing them into the disk.

```js
const express = require('express');
const multer  = require('multer');
const storage = multer.memoryStorage();
const upload = multer({ storage });

const app = express();

app.post('/submit', upload.array('images'), (req, res, next) => {
  // req.files is array of `images` files
  // I believe it is a `Buffer` object.
  const base64Images = req.files.map(image => buffer.toString('base64'));
  // Ready to save into DB;
  console.log(base64Images);
})
```